# Close console application window after key press or automatically after x minutes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, timer, console-application

I have a console application in Visual Studio 2008, C# and .NET Framework 3.5.

When application finishes to do all the stuff I want to close the windows when user press a key or automatically after some minutes have been elapsed.

So at the end of my application I do:

```
static System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

public static int Main(string[] args)
{
   // Do some stuff
   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close this window.");

   myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
   myTimer.Interval = 5000;
   myTimer.Start();

   Console.ReadKey();

   return 0;
}


private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)       
{
    myTimer.Stop();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

The problem here is that window is not close after x minutes has been elapsed and even timer event is never raised since program is blocked waiting for a key (ReadKey).

So how to do it?

Comment: You are using the wrong type of timer, you can't use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` in a console app like this, you need a timer that does not rely on a "UI Thread" like a `System.Timers.Timer`

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the work to be done into a separate thread:

```
public static int Main(...)
{
    new System.Threading.Thread(Work).Start();
}
private void Work()
{
    // work to be done here
}
```

This way the GUI thread will have time for raising the timer's tick event.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you are using a Form timer, which is hung up on a UI thread -- for a console app. You are exiting an environment not of the Console.

We need to use the threading timer instead. But, this should be not too much different.

```
    static Timer myTimer;

    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close this window.");

        //Hey, I just met you and this is crazy
        myTimer = new Timer(CallMeMaybe, null, 5000, 0);

        //so call me maybe
        Console.ReadKey();

        return 0;
    }

    //Instead of a tick, we have this
    private static void CallMeMaybe(object state)
    {
        //But here's my number
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution, but not sure if the best:

```
static System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

public static int Main(string[] args)
{
   // Do some stuff
   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close this window.");

   myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
   myTimer.Interval = 5000;
   myTimer.Start();

   // while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
   //{
   //     Application.DoEvents();
   //     Thread.Sleep(250);
   //}

   // Above code replaced with:
   Console.ReadKey(true);

   DisposeTmr();

   return 0;
}

private static void DisposeTmr() 
{
    myTimer.Stop();
    myTimer.Dispose();
}

private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)       
{
    DisposeTmr();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Problem with that solution is that this type of timer is synchronous and it is needed to use Application.DoEvents as explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx). Also the timer remains in a suspended state while the UI thread is sleeping so this can cause timer event handler not continue capturing timer events while the main UI thread is sleeping.

To avoid this, there are two options, System.Timers.Timer and System.Threading.Timer. I have implemented System.Threading.Timer solution as below and it works perfectly:

```
static System.Threading.Timer myTimer;

public static int Main(string[] args)
{
   // Do some stuff
   Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close this window.");

   myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);

   while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
   {          
        Thread.Sleep(250);
   }

   DisposeTmr();

   return 0;
}

private static void DisposeTmr() 
{
    if (myTimer != null)
    {
        myTimer.Dispose();
    }
}

private static void TimerCallback(Object myObject)       
{
    DisposeTmr();
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented pretty easily with async/await.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await DoStuff();
        await Task.WhenAny
        (
            Task.Delay(3000),
            ExitOnKeypress()
        );
    }

    private static async Task ExitOnKeypress()
    {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1);
        }
    }
}
```